# Can the tlperl folder in a (Windows) texLive installation be deleted or is it needed for the compilation of documents?

Tags: texlive, perl

I am currently looking for ways to minimise the size of my texLive installation. My question generally concerns all operating systems, but for now it would suffice for me to know this in the context of Windows: Can I safely delete the tlperl folder and still compile documents or is it somehow involved in the compilation process?

Comment: Most packages don't require Perl, but some do, for example the `glossaries` package. Also, it might be that TeXLive itself needs Perl for housekeeping tasks; I don't know for certain. If you want to save space, just delete Windows instead ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPalmer +1 for the suggestion to delete Windows. I think tlmgr needs Perl, too. On [this site](https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) under "Disaster recovery" Perl is mentioned. Biblatex's biber also uses Perl, I guess.

Comment: Ok, but would it affect the compilation of basic documents that only rely on very basic packages (amsmath, babel and the like)?

Comment: @PLO why don't you just cut and move it to an other location and try? I don't think it'll break very basic documents but don't guarantee it.

Comment: Because I don't have access to a Windows machine at the moment and my attempts to install it with Wine failed.

Comment: And why don't you just try and move the perl folder on your linux machine?

Comment: The folder tlperl does not exist in my linux installation as I just found out.

Comment: tlperl is (as far as I remember) a minimal installation of perl mostly to run the texlive installation and update scripts, you probably don't want to remove that although of course it's not actually used in any usual tex-edit-preview cycle.

Comment: @Skillmon Linux has basic necessities like Perl. TL uses whatever `perl` your distro provides. This is why I need to do gymnastics to get certain things to work: TL assumes much older Perl than I have, so stuff breaks :(.

Comment: @cfr I meant the tlperl folder. This way he could test whether it'd work with his documents without or with the perl scripts... I work on an Arch Linux box, so I know for the necessities for Perl and the problem with TL assuming old Perl versions is known to me (biber throws a warning on every run).

Answer (score 2):

No, please don't delete it! Many scripts in TeX Live, foremost the important scripts fmtutil and updmap are written in Perl and require tlperl.
In case you delete the folder you will be able to run already built formats, but anything else (like updates, missing formats, ...) Will not work.